# chat in sidebar on main page

Tags: feature-request, chat

On meta there is a 'x people chatting' window in the sidebar. On other sites I have seen that on the regular pages as well (like on superuser).

Can we have that here too?

Or should it be there and I just happen to not see it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**There already is... usually.**

It would appear that, for the moment, it seems to have, as Ahriman put it, "gone missing" much like the community promo ads occasionally do.

I have no idea why it happens (maybe someone who *does* know can address that) but it is there and, unless it's a major bug, it will likely return at some stage if you refresh the page.

Comment: I think the sidebar is a semi-randomized rotation between several things. I don’t really feel like this is a *useful* approach, but just based on watching it that seems to be what’s going on. At a guess, this is by-design, just don’t know *why*.

Comment: For me, its never there. Never. Whenever I encountered something I would have wanted to chat about I looked to the right and it was not there. As it (usually) wasn't something important anyway I just ignored it. Mostly because I never cared much about it anyway. Just now that I realized that it is there on meta (always) I thought I should bring it up.

Comment: Today it is here, so I'll mark your question as correct, it seems to be back again...